# JavaScript Object/Array to PHP Controller using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

I'm currently using Laravel as my PHP framework, where I've setup an Api Class which goes off and calls an external API.

However I'm looking to use this functionality over AJAX, with AngularJS, where I'm currently struggling to pass data from Javascript. Here's how it works:

The PHP API GET Call:

```
Api::get('users/all', ['order' => 'desc']);
```

This would create a GET request, to the api with the parameters `order=desc`. However so I don't have to create a route for each api call, I want to do this dynamically:

Angular service:

```
app.factory('Api', function($http) {

    return {
        query : function( method, path, data ) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'api',
                headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
                data: { 'method': method, 'path': path, 'data': data },
            });
        },
    }

});
```

Then my PHP controller:

```
    $method = Input::get('method');

    $path = Input::get('path');

    return Api::$method($path);
```

So this works, however I'm struggling to pass the 3rd array parameter from JS to PHP.

```
var json = '{"order": "desc"}';

Api.query('get', 'users/list', json)
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.test = response;
    });
```

In my PHP, I've tried to `json_decode` it with no success (no errors actually):

```
        $method = Input::get('method');

        $path = Input::get('path');

        $data = json_decode(Input::get('data'), true);

        return Api::$method($path, $data);
```

Anyone got any clues what the best way around this is?

Comment: What is problem? With your above code, I can receive the json_data from angularjs method and can call the external Api::$method($path,$data).  (my Api class is only mock)